# Multiple animations on one element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m making a front end react app. I want to have an element slide across the screen (left->right) and then spin back across the (right->left). The idea is that the element goes smoothly across the screen and then after reaching the edge of the screen gets “flicked back” to the starting point.
So the first animation would be smooth linear left to right. The second animation would be a rotating + right to left transition.
Is this possible?

```js
import animation from "../assets/animation.gif"

const Contact = () => {
...

return (
<>
...
<img src={animation} alt="pixel character walking" className="h-[8rem] w-[8rem] slide-right"></img>
</>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

```css
@keyframes slide-from-right {
  from {
    right: 100%;
  }
  to {
    right: -20%;
  }
}

/* Element to be moved. Must have position: absolute */
.slide-right {
  position: absolute;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 5%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  animation-name: slide-from-right, roll-back-left;
  animation-duration: 15s, 15s;
  animation-delay: 0s, 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes roll-back-left {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

I can get the element to go back and forth across the screen with infinite + alterations but I can’t get the rotation to only occur on the back path.

Comment: Cool cool. Unless you post the code we can't provide any help.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can also try using existing libraries like for ex: [animejs](https://animejs.com/). However, please include the code so we can help you.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't get the rotation to only occur on the back path - just don't introduce a rotation unti, say, 50% through your CSS animation keyframes (I assume you are using keyframes - without your code I'm afraid any answer will just be a guess).

Comment: I have added the corresponding code